# El formato del rmarkdown cambia al enviar por correo electronico "Gmail"

Tags: r, rstudio, r-markdown

Estoy desarrollando una plantilla con tablas de información para enviar a través de correo. Utilizo Kable_styling para dar formato; cuando doy knit me aparece tal como quiero pero cuando envío el correo al gmail el formato cambia, sobre todo el de las tablas.

Al correo lo envío mediante blastula.

```
{r,echo=FALSE,fig.align='center',fig.height=3,fig.width=3, size=10}

RD<-read.csv("C:/Users/ivan.correa/Documents/Activations - Alerting Engine Project/Alertas/AVAH.csv",sep = ",") 

{r,echo=FALSE}

RD%>%  filter(OWNER_EMAIL==params$Asesor_) %>% select(NAME,STOREID,CIUDAD,FECHA_FINALQA,PHONE,TO_EMAIL_1,
AGING)%>% group_by(NAME,STOREID,CIUDAD,FECHA_FINALQA,PHONE,TO_EMAIL_1,AGING) %>% 
kable(col.names = c("NOMBRE","STORE ID","CIUDAD","FECHA APROBADO", "TELEFONO", "EMAIL","AGING"), align = "c",digits = (0)) %>% 
kable_styling(latex_options = "basic", font_size = 11, position = "c", bootstrap_options = "bordered",
              protect_latex = TRUE)
```

[image: Asi es como me aparece al dar knit]

[image: Asi como llega al correo]

Este es el código para el envío del correo:

```r
setwd("C:/Users/Documents/Activations - Alerting Engine Project/")
tempreport <- file.path(getwd(),"Alerta.rmd")


a=1

for(i in 1:nrow(Lista %>% select(OWNER_EMAIL) %>% distinct())){
  
  print(i)
  Asesor_<- Lista %>% select(OWNER_EMAIL) %>% distinct() %>% slice(i) %>% as.character()
  
  print("2a7")
  
  parametros <- list(Comercial=Lista %>% filter(OWNER_EMAIL==Asesor_) %>% select(OWNER_EMAIL) %>% distinct() %>% as.character(),
                     Asesor_=Asesor_)
  
  
  email<-blastula::render_email(input = tempreport,render_options = list(params=parametros))
  print(parametros$Comercial)
  #En caso de no poder enviar imprimir mensaje que no se pudo enviar correo
  tryCatch(
    email %>%
      smtp_send(
      from="ivan@gmail.com",
      #to=Base %>% filter(CLIENTE==Asesor_) %>% select(CORREO) %>% distinct() %>% as.character(),
      to="osc@hotmail.com",
      #to=c("",""),
      cc="osc@gmail.com",
      #cc=""
      subject = glue("Correo de Prueba Rstudio"),
      credentials=creds_key("gmail_creds")
    ),error=function(e) {print(glue("No se le pudo enviar correo a {Asesor_}"))
      #a=rbind(a,Asesor_)
      #if(i==nrow(Alertas %>% select(Asesor) %>% distinct())){
      #openxlsx::write.xlsx(a,glue("{nrow(a)}_Usuarios que recibieron correo-{today()}"))
      #}
    }
  )
}
```

Comment: Cómo lo envías? haces un copia y pega de lo que sale luego del Knit?

Comment: lo envio desde un script de R, mediante blastula, se crea un markdwon por cada usuario y se le envia en el cuerpo del correo

Comment: Por lo que veo, blastula usa https://github.com/r-lib/commonmark que es un renderizador de markdown básico, por lo que en principio estamos hablando de dos cosas distintas kinitr por un lado y commonmark por el otro. Mi hipótesis es que lamentablemente  tenés una capacidad muy limitada de estilos sobre todo en cuanto a las tablas.

Comment: Lo raro es que este errro en el formato pasa cuando la remision del correo se realiza desde un Gmail, realice algo similar desde un correo de outlook y no se afecta tanto el formato, sin embargo mi correo corporativo esta asociado a Gmail, Gracias por tu respuesta @PatricioMoracho

Comment: Puede ser que la visualización de un correo difiera en un cliente gmail de un outlook, de hecho es así. Para aislar el problema del cliente, deberías hacer un preview, yo entiendo que ya en preview es probable que pierdas muchas características de estilo que te ofrece knit. De cualquier forma intentaré probarlo, cualquier cosa te comento.